# change url on res.redirect in expressjs

Tags: node.js, url, angularjs, express

```
app.get('/logout', function (req, res){

    req.url='/';
    console.log('req.url is ' + req.url);

    req.session.state = null;

    res.redirect('/login');
});
```

upon redirect, the 'url' remains the same. I want it to change it too. Which i tried to do using req.url. But it does not reflect on the url-bar. How do you change that?

Note:- I'm using Angularjs Routing so the `res.redirect` is not automatically updating the url.

Edit:-
Angular Code:-

```
$http({method: 'GET', url: '/logout'}).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log('happened');

        }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          // called asynchronously if an error occurs
          // or server returns response with an error status.
        });
```

Comment: Are you navigating the browser to `/logout` directly, or with something like `$http`?

Comment: @robertklep put up the edit:- its with $http service.

Comment: In that case, you need to perform the redirect internally in Angular.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default `res.redirect` will send a response with a 302 status code and a Location header with the URL you call the function with. So in your case something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Location: http://example.com/login/
```

You will need to handle this on the AngularJS side to change the URL.

Comment: Because you are using $http you will need to handle the 302 response in the success callback. I don't really know Angular but I think you could check the `status` argument to see if it is 302 and get the location header off the `headers` argument and do something like `$location.url(headers.Location)`.

Comment: Not sure if this answer is outdated because [res.redirect](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) allows you to specify the status code now. Just do `res.redirect(301, '/login')`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution above but no luck. I was getting the error: `header ‘authorization’ is not allowed according to header`

I searched a day and tried all solutions provided in the web for this problem, I set `res.header( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, Accept, Content-Type")` in several ways, studied many articles and performed many changes in my backend but seemed that firefox couldn't find `Authorization` that it was looking for.

but above answer gave me an idea to do `redirect` in a much easier way! I just send my url to front-end in the request response like below:

```
 res.status(201).json({
   message: "Order registered",
   redirectUrl: "http://localhost:3000/payment-check?query"
  })
```

Then in the front-end (reactJS), I do replace window location:

```
window.location = res.data.redirectUrl
```

and it redirects with no problem and in the best way.